# Bibtex Internals

Tags: bibtex, documentation

I would like to make modifications to my bibtex title, and this can be done by modifying \bibname. But when it comes to reducing the amount of space between the title "Bibliography" and the entries below, I want to know how much space is put there in the first place.

More generally, I am curious as to how the bibtex internals work. I can't seem to find any documentation on this. So my questions are:

1. Where I can find information on how bibtex formats the bibliography page(s)?
2. More specifically, what determines the amount of space between the title and the entries below?

Comment: The specific aspect depends on the class and its definition of the `thebibliography` environment. Usually it's what results from `\section{\refname}\begin{list}{...}` (if the class doesn't provide chapters) or `\chapter{\bibname}\begin{list}{...}`. It has nothing to do with BibTeX.

Comment: Ah, so I was looking in the wrong place. My understanding is that an environment like thebibliography is set by the documentclass and can then be further modified. Can I view the defaults for the standard documentclasses?

Comment: @egreg: I found it (i.e. the doc class I'm using) in article.cls under texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base. I would consider this a full answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BibTeX's output is a `.bbl` file containing a `thebibliography` environment. It's the duty of the document class to define this environment.

Usually it's something like

```
\section*{\refname}
\begin{list}{<code>}
<bib items>
\end{list}
```

for classes without chapters and

```
\chapter*{\bibname}
\begin{list}{<code>}
<bib items>
\end{list}
```

This may vary according to loaded packages; for example `natbib` intervenes on this, but it uses a `\bibsection` macro that's essentially equivalent to `\section*` or `\chapter*` in the cases above.

You can find the definition using `texdef` from the command line. For instance, the command line

```
texdef -t latex -c article -s thebibliography
```

will output

```
% article.cls, line 570:
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
```

Modifying it needs `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Note that it could be difficult to track down the actual definition in case `natbib` (or other packages, maybe) is used, because it redefines the environment at begin document. However, looking at the package code reveals

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
 \bibsection
 \parindent\z@
 \bibpreamble
 \bibfont
 \list{\@biblabel{\the\c@NAT@ctr}}{\@bibsetup{#1}\global\c@NAT@ctr\z@}%
 \ifNAT@openbib
   \renewcommand\newblock{\par}%
 \else
   \renewcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em \@plus.33em \@minus.07em}%
 \fi
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.\@m
 \let\NAT@bibitem@first@sw\@firstoftwo
    \let\citeN\cite \let\shortcite\cite
    \let\citeasnoun\cite
}{%
 \bibitem@fin
 \bibpostamble
 \def\@noitemerr{%
  \PackageWarning{natbib}{Empty `thebibliography' environment}%
 }%
 \endlist
 \bibcleanup
}%
```

Changing the space between the title and the first item is just inserting a suitable `\vspace` command before `\list`, in both cases.